# Using passworded git in cruisecontrol.NET

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

Sorry if the question is somehow too easy. I just wonder on how to add the information regarding the username and password to access the git repository on the `ccnet.config`. I found tag `<username>` and `<password>` but they seem not work for git (the ones I've seen were all using VSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIT uses ssh keys to access repositories.  Configuration on windows can be a little tricky.  If your CCNet instance is not running as a user you normally use git operations with (i.e. LocalService), then you'll need to setup your openssh keys, known_hosts file, and appropriate environmental variables so that the **LocalService** (or whatever user you're using) can access them.

The following wiki article is for the Jenkins CI server on Windows, but the solution is likely the same for your setup.

[Jenkins, GIT plugin and Windows](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-)

EDIT:

Some more tricks to getting this working in CCNet.

When using SSH:

Use public/private key authentication without a password and setup your known_hosts.  Create a .ssh directory in your user home directory (open a GitBash terminal that comes with msysgit and type PWD, that is your home directory).  In your .ssh directory create a known_hosts and drop a private key in it (id_rsa, id_dsa).  The known_hosts needs your SSH server's fingerprint so that CCNet isn't prompted to add it when it initiates a connection (this will result in a timeout).